# PHP Dynamic Filter for mySQL Query Side effect issue

Tags: php, mysqli, filter

I have created a function where adds to a query to select items that correspond:

```
// BUILD FILTER
    $filter = '';
    $dups = array();
    if ($filters) {
        foreach ($filters as $t => $v) {
            $key = substr_replace($t, '', 0, strpos($t, '|') + 1);
            if (!in_array($key, $dups)) {
                $dups[] = $key;
                $filter .= "AND {$key}  = '{$v}' ";
            } else {
                $filter .= "OR {$key}  = '{$v}' ";
            }
        }
    }
```

So lets assume for this example the filter is Colours.  Each `$key` will say `COLOUR` and each `$v` will be it's value, Blue and another Pink.

The filter is then added to an existing query :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product_filter f 
   LEFT JOIN product_allow a ON (a.prod_sku = f.prod_sku) 
   INNER JOIN product_image i ON (i.prod_sku = f.prod_sku) 
   INNER JOIN dh_product_basic b ON (b.prod_sku = f.prod_sku) 
   WHERE a.prod_status = 1 
    AND f.CATEGORY = '{$cate}' 
    AND i.prod_isMain = 1 {$filter} 
   GROUP BY b.prod_sku, b.prod_category 
   ORDER BY b.prod_price DESC";
```

Works fine, other than when two `$key` are the same, and so uses the `OR` operand it needs to be brackets around it `(f.GRADE = 'B' OR f.GRADE = 'A')`.

This type of filtering is a little new to me, so I am not sure how I would go about changing the top code so that if a bracket is needed, it adds it to the correct place.

Any ideas on how to improve this function ?

Thanks

Comment: what if you need to test not equality but whether a value is less than or greater than a supplied argument? What if you need to apply some function like data calculation? What if you need to use LIKE for some conditions?

Comment: Note that your SQL is vulnerable to injection.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Hiya, it will not be required to look for greater than values, or LIKE.  It is a filter which searched a filter table that already takes care of this.   I just cannot make it put a bracket around the OR statements.

Comment: My only other idea is to search upon each filter.  So download as much as i can, and then search the array and filter out each pass with a filter ?

Comment: The bad idea, a latter one.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best apporach, but I have managed to do it this way:

```
 // BUILD FILTER
    $filter = '';
    $dups = array();
    if ($filters) {
        foreach ($filters as $t => $v) {
            $key = substr_replace($t, '', 0, strpos($t, '|') + 1);
           if (!in_array($key, $dups)) {
                $dups[] = $key;
                $filter .= "AND {$key}  = '{$v}' "; // AND
            } else {
               $i = strripos($filter, "AND");
               $filter = substr_replace($filter, " (", $i+3, 0);
                $filter .= "OR {$key}  = '{$v}') ";  // OR
            }
        }
    }
```

So when it can see it will add an OR, it searches for the last AND, and then adds a bracket.  Seems to work, but any better suggests are very welcome.

Thanks